# Page layout Option Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have sub site using TeamSite template. I have active SharePoint Server Publishing under manage feature. In top site i have activate as well SharePoint Server Publishing and SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure .

The question is when i have create page in subsite, i still could not see the page layout option. Please advise, thank you

REgards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Page Layout can only be applied in a Publishing Page library page, not just any document library. If the Publishing Feature is enabled on the Site Collection and in the Sub Site, then there will be a **Pages** Library in the sub site. Page layouts can be selected in (and created and published to) this library only, not in any other document libraries.

Page Layouts can **not** be applied to just any document or wiki library, even if the Publishing Feature is enabled. The Publishing Feature creates a special library for publishing pages and one for publishing images (used in those publishing pages). In order to consume the benefits of the Publishing Feature, you'll need to use that specific publishing library.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean page layout for webpart page ?

If so, you can do this following :

1. go to your page library (SitePages for example) via site content
2. At ribbon click new document by choosing "Web Part Page"
3. You will be redirect to New Web Part page menu

Or, you can just type this url :
http://[your sharepoint site]/_layouts/15/spcf.aspx

Hope that help